# Is it possible to query on nested fields when using a custom class as an Ignite key?

Tags: ignite

Using Apache Ignite 2.7.6, I am trying to make a cache whose key is a custom class with several fields in it, and which is embedded in the value. The cache works, but the SQL interface is showing me null values for the fields in the nested key. What's more, when I make those fields the primary key of the table, the results seem to violate standard SQL by allowing multiple null values in the primary key. Is there any way to make this work?

A reproduce-able example follows:

```
@Test
public void testComplexKey() throws InterruptedException {
    val queryEntity = new QueryEntity(TestKey.class, TestValue.class);
    // I get the same results regardless of whether these 2 lines are present or not
    queryEntity.getFields().put("key", TestKey.class.getName());
    queryEntity.setKeyFieldName("key");
    // I get the same results regardless of whether this lines is present or not
    queryEntity.setKeyFields(Sets.newHashSet("key.firstName", "key.lastName"));
    queryEntity.getFields().put("key.firstName", String.class.getName());
    queryEntity.getFields().put("key.lastName", String.class.getName());
    queryEntity.getFields().put("data", String.class.getName());
    queryEntity.setTableName("test_values");
    val cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(
            new CacheConfiguration<TestKey, TestValue>()
                    .setName("test_values")
                    .setQueryEntities(Lists.newArrayList(queryEntity))
    );
    cache.put(new TestKey("Bob", "Jones"), new TestValue(new TestKey("Bob", "Jones"), "The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog"));
    cache.put(new TestKey("Jim", "Smith"), new TestValue(new TestKey("Jim", "Smith"), "The quick red dog jumped over the lazy brown fox"));
    Assertions.assertEquals("The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog", cache.get(new TestKey("Bob", "Jones")).data);
    // This assertion would fail - no rows found
    // Assertions.assertEquals("The quick red fox jumped over the lazy brown dog", cache.query(new SqlQuery<TestKey, TestValue>(TestValue.class, "firstName = 'Bob'")).getAll().stream().findFirst().orElseThrow().getValue().data);
    // This just to keep the test running and allow me to query the SQL interface
    while (true) Thread.sleep(10000);
}

@NoArgsConstructor // This is Lombok shorthand
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class TestKey {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    String firstName;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    String lastName;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class TestValue {
    @Getter
    @Setter
    TestKey key;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    String data;
}
```

The resulting SQL view is... fairly confusing:

[image: SQL View depicting two rows both with NULL/NULL primary key values]

Answer (score 2):

In the SQL-engine, your objects are all "flattened", so you refer to `key.firstName` just as `firstName`.

```
queryEntity.setKeyFields(Sets.newHashSet("firstName", "lastName"));
queryEntity.getFields().put("firstName", String.class.getName());
queryEntity.getFields().put("lastName", String.class.getName());
queryEntity.getFields().put("data", String.class.getName());
```

Most people find it easier to use the `@QuerySqlField` annotation on the properties you want to expose to SQL.

There's no need to include the key object in the value. Removing it will also remove the ambiguity over which "firstName" column you're referencing.

Comment: what if both classes had a field with the same name? how can we refrence them without ambiguity if everythign is flattened ?

Comment: I believe the behaviour is undefined. In short: don't!

Comment: So does that mean I can't use SQL when caching a class with nested objects, where each object has a field with the same name (like id) ?